# Is it possible to get a Kivy app window to automatically fit the size of a single label inside?

Tags: python, label, kivy

I have a simple Kivy app that displays a message to notify me should there be any new comic books to download. It runs on this code:

```
def build(self):

Window.size = (300, 300)
self.title = 'Comics Notificator'
self.icon = 'assets/icon.png'
return Label(text=to_display)
```

I was wondering if it was possible to get the main window to automatically fit the size of the label inside of it as opposed to setting it manually, since I can't really know the number of comic books there would be to download.

Thank you!

Comment: As the code stands, the 'Label` and the `Window` are the same size, because the default `size_hint` for the `Label` is (1.0, 1.0). So, it's not clear what you are asking. A little more information would help.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I think that the OP wants to calculate the size of the Label given a certain text, that is, the height of the Label depends on the font, and the width depends on the text and the font.

Answer (score 0):

The [texture_size](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.texture_size) property is the size of the text so make a binding with the size of Window, in the following example I show how it resizes when you add more characters to the text.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        label = Label(text="Stack Overflow", font_size="40dp")
        label.bind(texture_size=Window.setter('size')) # <---
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.on_timeout, 1)
        return label

    def on_timeout(self, dt):
        self.root.text += " :-)" 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```